# trouble getting twitter Icon to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use Material UI Icons. I downloaded the dependencies and have the files but it looks like the "import TwitterIcon from "node_modules/@mui/icons-material/Twitter";" in my code is
possibly incorrect. The code will compile but will not display the icon.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import TwitterIcon from "node_modules/@mui/icons-material/Twitter";

export default function Sidebar(){
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <h1>"hey"</h1>
      <TwitterIcon className="sidebar__twitterIcon" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the error in my terminal: `Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6 Failed to compile.`

```
./src/Sidebar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'node_modules/@mui/icons-material/Twitter' in 'C:\Users\Jeremy.Carpenter\twitter-clone2\src'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Comment: Is material-ui installed as a dependency for your project? You should probably import it from `@mui` instead of `node_modules`, i.e. `"@mui/icons-material/Twitter"`.

Comment: Oh, great! I voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.